# Wiping Motorola Milestone without working display

Tags: cyanogenmod, remote-access, motorola-milestone, remote-wipe

A pretty funny and tricky situation: I've got a Motorola Milestone with almost completely not working display. I know that it was a fall that probably damaged some cabling inside and now display only shows some colorful garbage on the top 5-7 mm section and everything else is dark or almost dark.

Everything else seems to be working on this phone: i.e. touchscreen is working (for example, I can blindly unlock the phone - according to haptic feedback, it unlocks), hardware keyboard is working, sound is working, etc.

I want to send it to service center, but I want to wipe sensitive phone contents (i.e. messages, contacts) first.

I also know that this phone was flashed with [Cyanogenmod 7 for Milestone](http://android.doshaska.net/cm7) and OpenRecovery. USB connection yields proper USB storage device with inserted MicroSD card exported on it.

What I've tried:

- My first instinct was to use USB debugging, just logging into the phone with `adb shell` and then running something like `recovery --wipe_data`. Alas, it doesn't work - this phone doesn't seem to have USB debugged turned on. Without any visual feedback, I guess I have no chances to travel through all the menus (Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging) to enable it.
- My another attempt was to log into recovery (given that this phone has OpenRecovery, it should be a breeze to use it to wipe the phone or at least access USB debugging bridge). While pressing "Camera" on power on seems to be working to get that "triangle" screen (at least I don't seem to get regular boot), I find myself struggling to press VolUp+Camera to get to recovery menu and then blindly selecting any items in probable recovery menu. May be a good visual guide with screenshots would help me here?
- My last attempt was using Google's Play settings to control this phone to remotely install some sort of remote control application - but, alas, it seems that this phone is long gone from my Google account.

What I've also thought of:

- Going to fastboot. Alas, it seems that Milestone does not have fastboot.
- Making screenshots to get some visual feedback. Long press on "power" seems to show some kind of 6 items menu, but when I select last menu item (I thought it's "Screenshot")
- Installing something using SD card - such as creating custom "install.zip" in SD card root with clever instructions to install remote controlling software - but, alas, I don't know anything about these mechanics.

So, anyone has any more ideas what can I do, given these funny limitations?